# Is it a bad idea to have a MassTransit consumer that handles multiple message types?

Tags: c#, .net, masstransit

Let's assume there are 3 domain events (messages) in a MassTransit application: IEvent1, IEvent2, IEvent3. Each event captures an occurence of smt. that happened in the domain. There are separate consumers (implementing the IConsumer<> interface) for each event type, and each consumer is responsible for its own part of the business logic.

Would it be appropriate in some situation to have a single consumer class handle three events - i.e. implement three interfaces:

```
class GenericConsumer: IConsumer<IEvent1>, IConsumer<IEvent2>, IConsumer<IEvent3>
```

For example, a consumer that performs some kind of audit or logging routine, so that all three messages are handled similarly: all messages are written to another database, log file, sent to an external message bus, etc. Or should it still be 3 different consumer classes each implementing a single IConsumer<> interface?

Will there be any performance or maintenance issues related to the fact that a single consumer implements several interfaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a great idea, actually. And encouraged when messages are closely related – such as recording audit events into an audit store. In fact, I've seen audit consumers with more than twenty `IConsumer<T>` methods without any issues.

> Bonus points for using a batch consumer to receive multiple at once to more efficiently write them to storage.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's a good idea but not the best.

If the business logic for each message type is simple, then it may be easier to have a single consumer handle all of the message types. You will also have a centralized place to make the changes, It will also reduce the code duplication as well.

However, if the business logic for each message type is complex, then it may be better to have separate consumers for each message type. This will make it easier to understand and maintain the code. May be better to have separate consumers for each message type. This will make it easier to add new message types or change the business logic for existing message types. And It will also follow the Single Responsibility Principle.